# SharePoint : How to add a reference from C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

How do I add a reference to SharePoint 2007 from C#. What is the name and location of the DLL please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the dll here @ this location **C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll**, Adding the reference you need to right click Reference in the VS Project select the above location and add it.

Comment: found it now.... I guess the reason why I was battling to find it is because I can't find a damn thing anymore since Windows Vista Search came along...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using source control, I would put your Microsoft.SharePoint.dll DLL into a seperate folder named something like lib, along with your other 3rd party DLLs, and add your project references to there. That way, when a developer gets the source code, the references won't be broken if their environment is set up differently.

Comment: I can't imagine a SharePoint developer developing on a machine that doesn't have SharePoint installed... But valid point nonetheless

Comment: It's good to remove the environmental dependencies though, and applies to not just sharepoint dlls.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the base SharePoint DLL is

> Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

and it's normally located in

> c:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\12\ISAPI